# How do i align a view in RelativeLayout to top-right corner

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, alignment

Im trying to figure out how to align a view in relative layout to its top right corner.
Currently it is aligned in top left corner.

A simple problem, yet I dont know how to do it.

Here is the code:

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gpsViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    this.relativeLayout.addView(gpsView,gpsViewLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

instead of

```
gpsViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

You may get in this way.

Comment: Is this diffrent from @DDoSAttack answer?

Comment: wooot, what a massive typo :) im so ashamed :D

Comment: @no9 PM is right. DDoSAttack answer is better than this. (BUT BOTH ARE RIGHT answers)...

Answer (score 5):

It is ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT instead of ALIGN_RIGHT

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT